# how to get local time and put it in a string

Tags: c++

I have a method `s` that has as parameter a date time.

How to write it in c++ ?

In `c#` it is:

```
string s(System.DateTime sd);
```

EDIT!
HOW TO CALL THE S METHOD?! also i would like to have in a string the hour, in another string the second..and so on

Another question is: how to convert the time in a string value that has: day, month, hours, min and seconds ?

Comment: Please stop tagging things `ubuntu` that have nothing to do with that Operating System. That you happen to be using it is not enough!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: That's only because you know the correct answer (i.e. `gmtime()`) is a standard C++ function. For a similar, reasonable question "when does daylight start?" it's quite important to know whether you're seeking a Ubuntu or a Windows answer, since there's no ISO C++ solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an example. google for `time.h` Below is pseudo code:

```
#include <time.h>

string getTime ()
{
    time_t timeObj;
    time(&timeObj);
    tm *pTime = gmtime(&timeObj);
    char buffer[100];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d%d%d", pTime->tm_hour, pTime->tm_min, pTime->tm_sec);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: and how to call the method from int main?

Comment: the thing is that my method need as a parameter the time gave in i guess a long value:). So I need to have string getTime( and here the time that i want to split in seconds,h,year..

Comment: This example mixes up C++ string objects C character arrays (C strings).  It also returns a pointer to a local variable (char buffer[100]), which will cease to be valid as the function exits.

Comment: @nategoose, `buffer[100]` will be copied to the `std::string` and we are returning by value, so there is no problem of function scope. Also `std::string` are implemented as "Copy On Write", thus returning by value doesn't have any optimization concern in above code.

Comment: @iammilind: You are right.  It's been longer than I thought  since I've worked in normal C++.

Comment: This is not local time. The question asked for local time. -1

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Boost Posix Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

It offers a whole set of classes to deal efficiently and reliably with dates, times, durations and parsing.

Answer (score 3):

```
char time_buf[21];
time_t now;
time(&now);
strftime(time_buf, 21, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%S:%MZ", gmtime(&now));
```

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813492/unix-timestamp-to-xml-date-time-conversion)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<ctime>` library to catch the current time:

```
time_t rawtime = time(&rawtime);
struct tm *timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
```

Now you have the `timeinfo` struct variable from which you can take the distinct values. More info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/).