# how to set data time as a parameter in a method?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

HI,

I have a method that needs to contain a data time as a parameter. how can i write this? `string data_time(c_time time); ? is it correct?.`

And secondly in the:

```
 string data_time(c_time time)
{
 i would like to save the hour, second, minute, month and year in different string values. how to do this? need some help. i am working in ubuntu.. thx
}
```

Comment: In your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124768/) one of the [answers]() was to check out `Boost.Datetime`. Have you done this? It has good documentation and easy enough to use.

Comment: duplicate of previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124768/how-to-get-local-time-and-put-it-in-a-string/6124891#6124891

Comment: i did;t get an answr to the first question:). if data_time(c_time is correct or not

Comment: I have edited my answer for the `string` part in the old question. Check there, as this question might get closed by Mods soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 'time_t' from ['ctime'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time_t/) module? Examples: [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/), [two](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/time.h/ctime.php), [three](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/150836)