# C++ Getting local time for saved games

Tags: date, datetime, ubuntu, time, terminal

I am making a game off Ubuntu through the terminal and one feature I would like to add is adding timestamps to the saved games.

Like the game would display "Save: (time)" and in time would be (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM) is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be a "rare" asker. But nice to meet you. And in case you want to practice upvoting ... now that you can ... feel free to practice on my profile ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current date you can use the command [date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date). See `man date` for more format options.

```
$ date +'%d/%m/%y %T'
26/10/13 16:29:56
```

In case you would like to compute the timestamp from C++, see [how to get local time and put it in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124768/how-to-get-local-time-and-put-it-in-a-string).